# Call Shopify product image

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I can call the URL for the image of a product with the following code

```
{{ product | img_url: "medium" }}
```

this ouputs:

```
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0087/0462/products/shirt14_medium.jpeg?v=1309278311
```

When I however use this liquid code in an `<img>` tag like this

```
<img src="{{ product | img_url: "medium" }}" />
```

the output is:

```
<img src="" />
```

How do I correctly display the image of a product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

`{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '600x600' | img_tag: product.featured_image.alt }}`

the same as:

`<img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '600x600' }}" alt="{{product.featured_image.alt}}" />`

---

or

---

`{{ product.images[0]| img_url: '600x600' | img_tag: product.images[0].alt }}`

the same as:

`<img src="{{ product.images[0] | img_url: '600x600' }}" alt="{{product.images[0].alt}}" />`

both of them will work.

Don't use "medium" those are deprecated, for more information see here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/deprecated-filters#named-size-parameters